# has no exported member 'MD_XXX_DIRECTIVES

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am new to Angular2. So I am in the process to use angular material in a project. But, I have those:

> "has no exported member MD_XXX_DIRECTIVES" errors (e.g: MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES,MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES).

These are **package.json** dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
    "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
    "@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/grid-list": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/icon": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
    "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
    "@angular2-material/list": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
    "@angular2-material/progress-circle": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/radio": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
    "@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.5-2"}
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Can you show us how you are doing your imports for the material design stuff?

Comment: `import {MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular2-material/sidenav";`

Comment: being that you have the `^` indicator on the material packages, I wonder if it didn't pull down a newer version that what you specified, which the newer versions moved to the Module concept keeping in line with Angular.  Can you remove the `^` on the material packages, then remove the packages and reinstall and see if it works?

Comment: Ok I'll try it now

Comment: When installing, I had errors:

`npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-material
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'angular2-material' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/monta/WebstormProjects/my-web-app/npm-debug.log`

Comment: You'll still need to leave the @symbol before the angular2. As in `"@angular2-material/sidenav": "2.0.0-alpha.5-2"`

Comment: Well, I think it worked for sidenav (I don't see the error anymore), but not for MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES.

Comment: Have you updated the `package.json` and removed/reinstall all the packages?

Comment: I feel confused. Can you tell me how?

Comment: for each of the angular-material packages in the `package.json`, you need to remove the `^` character.  Then either go through and manually remove their packages or just remove the entire `node_modules` directory and re-run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `^` identifier in the npm package version let npm install the latest version.  The latest versions no longer exports a Directive, but a Module.  Removing that, then removing the packages and installing the specifically needed version (2.0.0-alpha.5-2) allowed use of the Directive again.